# Найти форму, которая открывает файл

Tags: lazarus

У меня есть кнопка, при нажатии которой, открывается окно, где нужно выбрать файл. Хочу изменить имя этого окна, не могу никак найти. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо перейти по вкладке Dialogs - выбрать TOpenDialog - изменить Title